# Change the type of an a element

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have an `<a>` element that may or may not have an `href` attribute.

If this element doesn't have an `href` element, I get the following error from google.

`Links are not crawlable`.

Do we have a way to change the type of an `<a>` element and tell to the bot that this isn't a link anymore ?

```html
<a [href]="url">{{ text }}</a>
```

Or is as follow the only way

```html
<a *ngIf="url" [href]="url">{{ text }}</a>
<p *ngIf="!url">{{ text }}</p>
```

The best would be an angular solution, but any javascript is welcome.

Comment: An a-element should always have an href attribute, otherwise it's not an a-tag. It's only purpose is to have an href attribute. So yes, rendering a `<p *ngIf="!url">` is your best bet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @cloned mentioned, this the `a-element` need to have an `href`.

Here's how I have deal with a more complex angular example, since I wanted to change the type of the `a-element` to avoid copying myself.

```html
<a
  *ngIf="attributes?.url"
  [href]="attributes.url"
>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="customContent"></ng-container>
</a>
<div *ngIf="!attributes?.url">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="customContent"></ng-container>
</div>

<ng-template #customContent>
  <!-- The lot of content my element needed to be inside -->
</ng-template>
```